# Parsec flatpak fails to load libraries, disabling hardware acceleration

Tags: linux, nvidia, hardware-acceleration

I recently switched to Pop!OS, however, for some reason Parsec refuses to run properly with hardware acceleration. It tries to open the driver.  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so is actually present after installing vdpau-va-driver_0.7.4-7_amd64.deb

I've tried for a while now. Anyone with any tips on how to fix this?

Kind regards,
Jelmer

[image: Error given]